# qml Stackview: pop a page which is in another file

Tags: qt, qml, stackview

My Problem, is that I cant pop() a page out of the stack. 
Let me explain a little bit:

I have a page where a couple of items are displayed
Each item has a button, which open a new page on top of the stackview, where i can edit my item. 
This EditPage has a close button - which should: yeah,  you get it: close the page xD

which means that I want to pop the page from the stack

**MainView.qml**

```
// ...

StackView {
    id: _myStack
    initialItem: _myView

    GridView {
      id: _myView       
      model: // comes from c++
      delegate: MyItem{}
    }
}
```

**MyItem.qml**

```
Item{
  id: _myItem

  Button{
    id: _buttonEdit
    text: "Edit"
    onClicked{
      _stackview.push("../components/Edit.qml, {some properties I pass through}, MainView.Immediate)   
       // Edit.qml is in another folder, import is done
    }
  }
}
```

**Edit.qml**

```
Page{
  id: _editPage

  // some code

  Button {
    id: _closeButton

    onClicked{
      //
      // here I want to pop this window out of the stack (it is the top item on the stack)
      // _myStack.pop() doesn't work - because _myStack is not visible
    }
}
```

what can I do? i have already tried this in Edit.qml: bit i stuck at this point - 
where to bind the signal in MyItem.qml or?

```
Page{
  id: _editPage

  signal closeEditPage

  Button {
    id: _closeButton

    onClicked{
       closeEditPage()
    }
}
```

Comment: you have [StackView.view](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#view-attached-prop) to access the view control. but these problems usually indicate errors in the application architecture. QML is declarative language, but you try to work with in imperative style.

Comment: Thats probably the reason why I constantly walk into dead ends. Apart from this ,  I can't access the _myStack.view. so my “middle“ page must somehow either get the view from MainView.qml or the signal from the editPage, right? I have to pass the information through like in a chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebind attached property [StackView.view](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-stackview.html#view-attached-prop) for easier access.

```
Page{
  id: _editPage

  property StackView _myStack: StackView.view

  Button {
    id: _closeButton

    onClicked{
       _myStack.pop()
    }
}
```

Comment: At the end i took your approach eri, rather than pass through the closePage signal.
thank you